# Send an Active FTP Request to FTP Server via jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ftp, load-testing, stress-testing

I just started using `jmeter` to load test FTP Server.
I am aware that jmeter by default sends passive connection request to the FTP Server via the default `FTP Request sampler`.

I wanted to know what's the best and simplest way using which i can change the request to `active mode`.
I did find multiple posts about samplers but none of them were straight forward nor had clear steps on how to write your own sampler and run it.

If you have any suggestion for any other open source FTP Stress testing which support both passive and active requests. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [FTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request) sampler provides very limited configuration and possibilities, i.e. you cannot even list files in the FTP server's directory, rename a file, delete a file, etc. so if you need to implement something apart from uploading/downloading files - you will have to go for [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language

JMeter uses Apache's [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) which provides [`enterRemoteActiveMode()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterRemoteActiveMode-java.net.InetAddress-int-) so you can use these JSR223 Samplers for simulating "active" clients.

More information: [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)